# I have to add condition in Magento 1.9 to check if its mobile device

Tags: magento-1.9, mobile

I am working on Magento 1.9 and i want to check condition for mobile using php code how can i do this? can anybody help to figure out this?

Comment: You can use media query to make responsive.

Comment: @Kul sorry but i want to put condition using php code to add class when page open in mobile device

Comment: Please check i have added answer hope it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below condition . It's work for me for detect mobile device.

```
$isMobile = Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match(
    Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(),
    $_SERVER
);
```

Note: If you are testing in desktop or laptop by Responsive design view. It will not work. Its only work in mobile.

Comment: if this not work for anyone. try to remove browser cache if you have already open website in mobile.

Comment: It will not show results if resize browser, only work in actual devices.

Comment: @Paarth Yes. Its php side code. it will used to add php conditon or class while load page. if you resize page it will not work. you have to used Js code to achieve it.

Comment: @Kul I want to use your method. Where would you recommend adding this condition?

Comment: you can include it in block/helper method and then use it in template if required